# Good coding practice js function()

Tags: javascript, html, function

Is it a good practice and it is security save to always put a js function in modern coding web pages like this:

```
<div onclick="dosomething(a,b,id)">wow</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No...just no you shouldnt put a onclick event in a div when you **DO NOT** require to have one in there.